# Error Phonegap App with Mobile Angular Ui

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, phonegap-build

I'm following this guide
http://mobileangularui.com/blog/your-first-phonegap-app-with-mobile-angular-ui/#why-not-just-twitter-bootstrap-and-angular-ui-

but when i run this code

```
npm install -g bower yo gulp generator-mobileangularui
```

I receive this error...

```
   C:\Users\Desktop\Sorgente\weather>npm install -g bower yo gulp
    generator-mobileangularui


> npm WARN engine yo@1.4.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.0"}

 (current:
    {"node":"v0.10.29","npm":"1.4.14"})
    |


    > buffertools@2.1.2 install C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
    odules\generator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode\node_mod
    ules\bufferstream\node_modules\buffertools
    > node-gyp rebuild


    C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-mobileangul
    arui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode\node_modules\bufferstream\node_modul
    es\buffertools>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\
    ..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
    MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\n
    ode_modules\unicode\node_modules\bufferstream\node_modules\buffertools\build\bi
    nding.sln]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
    ` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
    npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:809:
    12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
    les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generato
    r-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode\node_modules\bufferstre
    am\node_modules\buffertools
    gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.29
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing buffertools@2.1.2
    |


> unicode@0.6.1 postinstall C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\generator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\node_modules\unicode
> node install.js

try to read file /usr/share/unicode/UnicodeData.txt .
Warning: using slow naiv Buffer.indexOf function!
`npm install buffertools` to speed things up.
/usr/share/unicode/UnicodeData.txt not found.
try to read file /usr/share/unicode-data/UnicodeData.txt .
/usr/share/unicode-data/UnicodeData.txt not found.
try to read file UnicodeData.txt .
UnicodeData.txt not found.
try to download .
GET unicode.org:80/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt
fetching .
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\yo -> C:\Users\Ap
pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js



> yo@1.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\yo
> yodoctor

/
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

V Global configuration file is valid
V NODE_PATH matches the npm root
V No .bowerrc file in home directory
V No .yo-rc.json file in home directory

Everything looks all right!
C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\bower -> C:\Users
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower
gulp@3.8.11 C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp
├── interpret@0.3.10
├── pretty-hrtime@0.2.2
├── deprecated@0.0.1
├── archy@1.0.0
├── tildify@1.0.0 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── minimist@1.1.1
├── v8flags@2.0.5 (user-home@1.1.1)
├── semver@4.3.4
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0.2.0, escape-string-regexp@1
.0.3, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── orchestrator@0.3.7 (stream-consume@0.1.0, sequencify@0.0.7, end-of-stream@0.
1.5)
├── liftoff@2.0.3 (extend@2.0.1, flagged-respawn@0.3.1, resolve@1.1.6, findup-sy
nc@0.2.1)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.13 (graceful-fs@3.0.6, strip-bom@1.0.0, vinyl@0.4.6, defaults@1
.0.2, mkdirp@0.5.0, glob-stream@3.1.18, glob-watcher@0.0.6, through2@0.6.5)
└── gulp-util@3.0.4 (array-uniq@1.0.2, array-differ@1.0.0, beeper@1.0.0, lodash.
_reevaluate@3.0.0, object-assign@2.0.0, lodash._reescape@3.0.0, lodash._reinterp
olate@3.0.0, replace-ext@0.0.1, vinyl@0.4.6, chalk@1.0.0, dateformat@1.0.11, lod
ash.template@3.5.1, through2@0.6.5, multipipe@0.1.2)

generator-mobileangularui@1.2.1 C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\generator-mobileangularui
├── chalk@0.4.0 (ansi-styles@1.0.0, has-color@0.1.7, strip-ansi@0.1.1)
├── yosay@0.1.0 (pad-component@0.0.1, word-wrap@0.1.3, minimist@0.0.9)
├── slug@0.5.0 (unicode@0.6.1)
└── yeoman-generator@0.16.0 (dargs@0.1.0, diff@1.0.8, debug@0.7.4, isbinaryfile@
2.0.4, class-extend@0.1.1, rimraf@2.2.8, async@0.2.10, findup-sync@0.1.3, mime@1
.2.11, text-table@0.2.0, mkdirp@0.3.5, iconv-lite@0.2.11, shelljs@0.2.6, lodash@
2.4.2, underscore.string@2.3.3, glob@3.2.11, file-utils@0.1.5, request@2.30.0, c
heerio@0.13.1, inquirer@0.4.1, download@0.1.19)

yo@1.4.6 C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo
├── titleize@1.0.0
├── array-uniq@1.0.2
├── figures@1.3.5
├── user-home@1.1.1
├── humanize-string@1.0.1 (decamelize@1.0.0)
├── opn@1.0.2
├── string-length@1.0.0 (strip-ansi@2.0.1)
├── async@0.9.0
├── sort-on@1.2.0 (dot-prop@2.0.0)
├── yeoman-character@1.0.1 (supports-color@1.3.1)
├── cross-spawn@0.2.9 (lru-cache@2.6.2)
├── findup@0.1.5 (commander@2.1.0, colors@0.6.2)
├── root-check@1.0.0 (downgrade-root@1.1.0, sudo-block@1.2.0)
├── yosay@1.0.3 (ansi-styles@2.0.1, word-wrap@1.0.3, ansi-regex@1.1.1, strip-ans
i@2.0.1, pad-component@0.0.1, taketalk@1.0.0, minimist@1.1.1)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1
.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── meow@3.1.0 (object-assign@2.0.0, camelcase-keys@1.0.0, indent-string@1.2.1,
minimist@1.1.1)
├── update-notifier@0.3.2 (is-npm@1.0.0, latest-version@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.0.0
)
├── npm-keyword@1.1.1 (registry-url@3.0.3)
├── package-json@1.1.0 (registry-url@3.0.3)
├── got@2.9.2 (lowercase-keys@1.0.0, is-stream@1.0.1, timed-out@2.0.0, prepend-h
ttp@1.0.1, nested-error-stacks@1.0.0, infinity-agent@2.0.3, statuses@1.2.1, obje
ct-assign@2.0.0, read-all-stream@2.1.2, duplexify@3.3.0)
├── fullname@1.1.0 (npmconf@2.1.1)
├── configstore@0.3.2 (xdg-basedir@1.0.1, object-assign@2.0.0, osenv@0.1.0, grac
eful-fs@3.0.6, uuid@2.0.1, mkdirp@0.5.0, js-yaml@3.3.0)
├── insight@0.5.3 (object-assign@2.0.0, lodash.debounce@3.0.3, tough-cookie@0.12
.1, os-name@1.0.3, request@2.55.0)
├── yeoman-doctor@1.3.2 (object-values@1.0.0, log-symbols@1.0.2, each-async@1.1.
1, twig@0.7.2)
├── yeoman-environment@1.2.5 (untildify@2.0.0, log-symbols@1.0.2, escape-string-
regexp@1.0.3, diff@1.4.0, text-table@0.2.0, debug@2.1.3, grouped-queue@0.3.0, gl
obby@1.2.0, mem-fs@1.1.0)
├── lodash@3.8.0
└── inquirer@0.8.3 (cli-width@1.0.1, ansi-regex@1.1.1, through@2.3.7, readline2@
0.1.1, rx@2.5.2)

bower@1.4.1 C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower
├── is-root@1.0.0
├── junk@1.0.1
├── stringify-object@1.0.1
├── chmodr@0.1.0
├── which@1.0.9
├── abbrev@1.0.5
├── rimraf@2.3.3
├── user-home@1.1.1
├── lockfile@1.0.0
├── opn@1.0.2
├── bower-logger@0.2.2
├── bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2
├── graceful-fs@3.0.6
├── archy@1.0.0
├── nopt@3.0.1
├── retry@0.6.1
├── lru-cache@2.6.2
├── semver@2.3.2
├── p-throttler@0.1.1 (q@0.9.7)
├── tmp@0.0.24
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── q@1.3.0
├── shell-quote@1.4.3 (array-filter@0.0.1, array-reduce@0.0.0, array-map@0.0.0,
jsonify@0.0.0)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1
.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── promptly@0.2.0 (read@1.0.5)
├── bower-json@0.4.0 (intersect@0.0.3, deep-extend@0.2.11, graceful-fs@2.0.3)
├── insight@0.5.3 (object-assign@2.0.0, lodash.debounce@3.0.3, async@0.9.0, toug
h-cookie@0.12.1, os-name@1.0.3)
├── glob@4.5.3 (once@1.3.2, inflight@1.0.4, inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@2.0.7)
├── fstream@1.0.5 (inherits@2.0.1)
├── fstream-ignore@1.0.2 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@2.0.7)
├── cardinal@0.4.4 (ansicolors@0.2.1, redeyed@0.4.4)
├── decompress-zip@0.1.0 (mkpath@0.1.0, touch@0.0.3, binary@0.3.0, readable-stre
am@1.1.13)
├── tar-fs@1.5.0 (pump@1.0.0, tar-stream@1.1.4)
├── github@0.2.4 (mime@1.3.4)
├── request@2.53.0 (caseless@0.9.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, tunnel
-agent@0.4.0, oauth-sign@0.6.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, isstream@0.1.2, strin
gstream@0.0.4, qs@2.3.3, node-uuid@1.4.3, combined-stream@0.0.7, mime-types@2.0.
11, form-data@0.2.0, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@2.3.1, tough-cookie@1.1.0, bl@0
.9.4)
├── update-notifier@0.3.2 (is-npm@1.0.0, string-length@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.0.0,
 latest-version@1.0.0)
├── bower-registry-client@0.3.0 (rimraf@2.2.8, request-replay@0.2.0, graceful-fs
@2.0.3, lru-cache@2.3.1, mkdirp@0.3.5, async@0.2.10, request@2.51.0)
├── mout@0.11.0
├── handlebars@2.0.0 (optimist@0.3.7, uglify-js@2.3.6)
├── bower-config@0.6.1 (osenv@0.0.3, graceful-fs@2.0.3, optimist@0.6.1, mout@0.9
.1)
├── configstore@0.3.2 (object-assign@2.0.0, xdg-basedir@1.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, uuid
@2.0.1, js-yaml@3.3.0)
└── inquirer@0.8.0 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, mute-stream@0.0.4, through@
2.3.7, readline2@0.1.1, chalk@0.5.1, lodash@2.4.2, rx@2.5.2, cli-color@0.3.3)

C:\Users\Desktop\Sorgente\weather>yo mobileangularui

Error: Cannot find module 'unicode/category/So'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at symbols (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gener
ator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\slug.js:6:16)
    at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-mobi
leangularui\node_modules\slug\slug.js:123:5
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\generator-mobileangularui\node_modules\slug\slug.js:130:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I installed the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK but I have the same problem...How can fix it???

My versions:

```
C:\Users\bla>npm -v
1.4.14

C:\Users\bla>node -v
v0.10.29

C:\Users\bla>cordova -v
4.3.0
```

Comment: As you can see, it expects an npm version of at least 2.1.0 (`wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0","npm":">=2.1.0"}`). Try upgrading your npm

Comment: This is a warning and not a error...there are another error!

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
node-gyp rebuild --msvs-version=2012
```

Also works with:

```
--msvs-version=2013
```